# Which key is Num Lock on an Apple keyboard in Windows?

Tags: keyboard, windows

I have an extended keyboard as in the image below

[image]

When connecting to a Windows machine, which key is Num Lock?

For future reference, the key on this UK keyboard does not say <kbd>Clear</kbd>, it has an image of a horizontal rectangle with an X through it <kbd>⌧</kbd> but it is the same key and provides the same functionality in OS X.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Under Boot Camp, it's the <kbd>Clear ⌧</kbd> button, according to [Apple's documentation](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1216).

That makes some sense, at least, because that key is where <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> normally lives on other keyboards.

(Note: I don't have the same keyboard to test with, but I'm guessing this document isn't actually Boot Camp-specific; it's just a guide to how the keys are mapped under Windows.)

Comment: What if you don't have the `clear` button?

Comment: Can confirm this works on the newer magic keyboards with numpads as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the combination <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Clear ⌧</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

1. Windows Key (on a Magic Keyboard with Numeric Keypad - US English - Silver) it is the Command Key.
2. Type Onscreen and the On-Screen Keyboard Application appears.
3. Select "Options" (Lower Right, next to Help)
4. Enable numeric keypad
5. You are done!

Answer (score 1):

I have an Apple wireless keyboard without a separate numeric keypad. Nonetheless, the main part of the keyboard is disabled when numlock is engaged, so toggling it is even more important on this keyboard. As suggested in other answers, <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> toggles numlock.

I added this answer in addition to the other answers because it wasn't clear that <kbd>fn</kbd> was necessary in my case.

Answer (score 0):

left shift + key over number 7

that works for me

Comment: That's the Clear key, as already answered.

Comment: (F6) Turned out to be helpful: there is no marked "clear" key in the keypadless version.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a [Logitech MX Keys for Mac keyboard](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/products/keyboards/mx-keys-mac-wireless-keyboard.920-009552.html) and need the Num lock key - it's <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>clear</kbd>.

I used the Logitech Options software to map the eject key to Num lock if you like to hit one key and haven't already mapped that key that Windows doesn't use to another function.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

1. Ease of Access Center
2. Start on screen keyboard
3. Options
4. Turn on numeric key pad

Comment: What is "Ease of Access Center"?

Answer (score -3):

You can take the following steps:

1. click a SYSTEM PREFERENCES
2. click a accessibility
3. click a mouse & trackpad
4. click a enable mouse keys

Comment: In what way does this answer the question?